# How do I find all the different cases of convergence/divergence of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Find if sum converges or diverges
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ 1}{n(\ln n)^p(\ln(\ln n)^q }
\end{equation}
I know how to answer the question if $q=1$ and $p=1$ (through integral comparison) 
But I'm can't seem to solve other cases.
Any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing convergence of series $\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{n (\ln(n))^p(\ln\ln(n))^q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825008/testing-convergence-of-series-sum-n-3-infty-frac1n-lnnp-ln-lnn) (Found with [Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=test&p=1)).

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $p>1$,  the *Bertrand's series* $\; \displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1{n\ln^p n}$ converges (by the integral test)   and
$$\frac{ 1}{n\ln^pn \,\bigl(\ln(\ln n)\bigr)^q}=o\biggl(\frac{ 1}{n\ln^pn}\biggr)\dots $$